# What is the proper syntax in Postgres for addressing tables?

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, database-connection

In sql-server, one can connect to the master db and write a statement in the below syntax to query any table:

```
SELECT * FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
```

I've ran some google searches for "postgres full table address" and "postgres object hierarchy" but to no avail. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032751/what-is-the-proper-syntax-in-sql-server-for-addressing-tables) for more on how this is done in sql-server.

Are operations like this possible in Postgres (I'm running version 9.3)?

- If so, please explain how with a code example.
- If not, please explain why not.

Comment: it's the same, database.schema.table. did you even try it before posting?

Comment: Yup, I tried and receive the following error: ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: "DBname.public.TABLEname"

Comment: Also, why the down vote? I know this is a rookie question, but for someone new to Postgres I think it's a valid thing to ask here.

Comment: not my down vote. If you've tried something and received an error, it's best to include that in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Table Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html) in the manual:

> A table reference can be a table name **(possibly schema-qualified)**,
>   or a derived table such as a subquery, a table join, or complex
>   combinations of these

That's it. No database name is allowed.

If a session has to refer to tables in a different database than it's connected to, it should use a [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html), or a [foreign table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigntable.html) through a data wrapper. In PostgreSQL, the databases within the same instance are deeply insulated from each other. When different namespaces are needed, schemas are used as opposed to databases.